# Split a column into two selecting text

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
df = [{"username": "last",
"time_data": "{\"hours\":[{\"hour\":\"00:00\",\"postCount\":\"5\",\"topicCount\":\"3\",\"totalCount\":80},{\"postCount\":\"20\",\"topicCount\":\"11\",\"name\":\"Marketplace\",\"url\",\"totalCount\":31},{\"postCount\":\"26\",\"topicCount\":\"1\",\"name\":\"Atari 5200\",\"url\",\"totalCount\":27},{\"postCount\":\"9\",\"topicCount\":0,\"name\":\"Atari 8\",\"url\"\"totalCount\":9}"
},
{"username": "truk",
 "time_data": "{\"hours\":[{\"hour\":\"00:00\",\"postCount\":\"11\",\"topicCount\":\"6\",\"totalCount\":362},{\"postCount\":\"333\",\"topicCount\":\"22\",\"name\":\"Hardware\",\"url\",\"totalCount\":355},{\"postCount\":\"194\",\"topicCount\":\"8\",\"name\":\"Marketplace\",\"url\",\"totalCount\":202}"
}]
df = pd.DataFrame(df)
df
```

I have runned this code:

```
df_h0 = df.copy()
df_h0['hour']='00:00' 
df_h0['totalCount']=df.post_time_data.str.split('"00:00","postCount":"').str[1].str.split('","topic').str[0]
df_h0 = df_h0.fillna(0)
df_h0.head()
```

But actually, I need to get the number after the "totalCount". I don't know how to do it since there are others "totalCount" and the one that I need it the one after the "00:00".

This is the expected output:

```
       hour    totalCount   username
0     00:00       80         last
1     00:00       362        truk
```

Comment: It appears that there's a hanging key with no value, `url`, in all of these records, is that supposed to be that way?

Comment: This looks alot like a json string, except that `url` has no value in the records.  If that is supposed to be the case, then you'll probably have to use regular expressions, otherwise it is possible to make it much easier using `json_normalize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your position I'd investigate the source of that strings which try to imitate *json* representation. Make sure that the respective dictionaries could not be retrieved/extracted instead.
But in case you're not allowed to do that you may go with `Series.str.extract` function:

```
In [230]: df_h0['totalCount'] = df['time_data'].str.extract(r'totalCount\":(\d+)')                                                             

In [231]: df_h0                                                                                                                                
Out[231]: 
  username   hour totalCount
0     last  00:00         80
1     truk  00:00        362
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df_h0 = df.copy()
df_h0['hour']='00:00' 
df_h0['totalCount']=df.time_data.str.split('"totalCount":').str[1].str.split("}").str[0]
df_h0.drop("time_data", axis=1)
df_h0
```

Output:

```
  username   hour totalCount
0     last  00:00         80
1     truk  00:00        362
```